# IE Proxy Exceptions List

Tags: internet-explorer, proxy, script, exceptions

Does anyone have a script that can modify the proxy server exceptions list in Internet Explorer?  If so, is it compatible with IE6 and up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I just found this link from Microsoft which explains it:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/819961/

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to use a `proxy.pac` file.

Comment: Why? What about it makes it easier or better? How would one use it if they chose to? It is good to give more detailed information about a solution, especially if it is an alternate solution to what the OP asks.

Comment: Sorry, must have been a bad day when I answered! proxy.pac files give a lot more control over the proxy process. For example, you can automate the selection of a proxy dependent on your current network. It is a subset of JavaScript with some variables available.